# Spring MVC - Ehcache best practices

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I have a question about best pratices using spring and ehCache.

For example if I have two methods annotated with @Cacheable that are using the same parameter value, ehcache will  return the latest cache value.

```
@Cacheable(value="imagesCache",key="#id_image")
public Image getUserImage(id_image){ //stuff }

//and 

@Cacheable(value="imagesCache",key="#id_image")
public Image getProductImage(id_image){ //stuff }
```

If I first call getUserImage(**10**) and then getProductImage(**10**), ehcache will return same value for both methods because they have the same key.
I tought that ehcache, indexes the cache value using **key and method name**, so that if two methods have the same #key(10 in my example) it will look at the method name.

I know that the easiest solution is to create two caches ("userImagesCache" and "productImagesCache") but in this context I want to avoid this.

How to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you not want two separate caches? The users and products seem like distinct sets.

Comment: Beacuse in the end I will get tens of caches. An user can have images, addresses, phones and some of them may have same key...

Comment: Underneath it all, Spring is actually using AOP to intercept the method calls, create a cache key, and cache the method responses. You can all this yourself using the spring config rather than annotations. Then you can implement your own 'interceptor' which creates keys of your own devising. Though @retoq seems to provide the correct answer here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to `@Cacheable` javadoc `key` is a SpEL expression, so you might to make smth like that:

```
@Cacheable(value="imagesCache",key="'user' + #id_image")
public Image getUserImage(id_image){ //stuff }

//and 

@Cacheable(value="imagesCache",key="'product' + #id_image")
public Image getProductImage(id_image){ //stuff }
```

Comment: That sounds right, let me test it and then I will accept your answer. Thanks